# Django form.py not updating

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8

I have been going through the [Django forms 'tutorial'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/). Once I had read through the tutorial, I tried modifying it to suit my needs and customize it to learn it Django forms well. I discovered whenever I modified the form, the website would not update. I assume its an error with my code, but I have not been able to find it.

```
# views.py
def contact(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/message_recived/')

# forms.py
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(label='Message', max_length=500)


# models.py
from django.db import models
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

and here is the `contact.html` template:

```
#contact.html
{% extends "BlogHome/headerAndFooter.html" %}
{% block content %}
<script>
document.title = "Pike Dzurny - Contact"
</script>
<form action="/message_recived/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Did I do something wrong? I have tried clearing my browsers cache, using a new browser, and obviously refreshing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your forget to [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) response inside your view.
Also you need to include form into context to render template right.

Try to change view as follow:

```
def contact(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/message_recived/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()       
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: @PikeD. hm, can you check when you open page in browser if it is correct template or not? Can you see form on the page?

Comment: Okay, I just looked in my templates, and it looks like there is a duplicate of my templates except one is `contact.html` and the other `Contact.html`, it looks like I was editing the `Contact.html`. I then copy and pasted the HTML into `contact.html` and it seems like it is still now it is not rendering the form at all.

Comment: @PikeD. Check if headerahdfooter template has block named content. Also try to add test text inside this block in contact.html and check if it was updated in browser.

Comment: Added a test `<p>TEST</p>` to the page, it updated with it. I also tried doing `{{ form.as_p }}` and `'{{ form.as_table }}` they both didn't effect the page. The headerandfooter does contain a block named contact, should I change it?

Comment: @PikeD. Try to add print(form) before return render() line and check what will be printed. Btw are you shure you are using contact view?)

Comment: Yes, I checked I was going to the right contact. Also, how do I see what is outputted? I accepted your answer because you helped me solve one problem (wrong file).

Comment: @PikeD. You can see output in shell. When you run django like python manage.py runserver the python will print system message, if you add print to view you can see this message also.